# Looping through names on a list to run through another program in Python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, twitter, pandas

I've been trying to run a list of twitter user names through a Python script that downloads their tweet history from Twitter's API. I have the user names as a csv file that I tried to import into a list and then pass through the script one-by-one using a for-loop. However, I am getting this error as it seems to be dumping the entire list into the script at once:

```
<ipython-input-24-d7d2e882d84c> in get_all_tweets(screen_name)
     60 
     61         #write the csv
---> 62         with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
     63                 writer = csv.writer(f)
     64                 writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])

IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '0       TonyAbbottMHR\n1              AlboMP\n2     JohnAlexanderMP\n3      karenandrewsmp\n4
```

For brevity's sake, I am just including a list in the code, with the importing of names from the csv to the list commented out.

Apologies, but in order to run the script, one needs a Twitter API. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import tweepy #https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd

#Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""

os.chdir('file/dir/path')

mps = [TonyAbbottMHR,AlboMP,JohnAlexanderMP,karenandrewsmp]
#df = pd.read_csv('twitMP.csv')

#for row in df:
    #mps.append(df.AccName)   

def get_all_tweets(screen_name):
    #Twitter only allows access to a users most recent 3240 tweets with this method

    #authorize twitter, initialize tweepy
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []  

    #make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200)

    #save most recent tweets
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    #save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

    #keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(new_tweets) > 0:
        print "getting tweets before %s" % (oldest)

        #all subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)

        #save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

        #update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1

        print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))

    #transform the tweepy tweets into a 2D array that will populate the csv 
    outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]

    #write the csv  
    with open('%s_tweets.csv' % screen_name, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(["id","created_at","text"])
        writer.writerows(outtweets)

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pass in the username of the account you want to download
    for i in range(len(mps)):
        get_all_tweets(mps[i])
```

Comment: You definitely want to print ```screen_name``` before passing it to the ```get_all_tweets``` function  to make sure you are running it correctly.

Comment: what is `mps.append(df.AccName)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Padraic: I wanted to build a list of each user name to pass through the script from a list of twitter user names I had in a csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this

```
#df = pd.read_csv('twitMP.csv')

#for row in df:
    #mps.append(df.AccName)
```

portion of your code is giving you troubles.

Here are your problem(s)

#### Problem 1

When ones iterates over a `DataFrame` object, you will actually iterate over it's column names, so you do not want to do that. You can see this by running `list(df)` which returns a list of the column names.

#### Problem 2

When you append `df.AccName` you are in fact appending the entire column. So in the end, `mps` becomes a list of `DataFrame` columns, each element identical and equal to `df.AccName`.

#### Solution

All you need to do is

```
df = pd.read_csv('twitMP.csv')
mps = df.AccName.tolist() #or df.AccName.astype(str).tolist() if they aren't strings, but they should be
```

#### Bonus

When you loop over mps, try using `enumerate`, you get two variables, and the code is cleaner in my opinion

```
for i,name in enumerate( mps):
    get_all_tweets( name )
```

You can still use the index of `name` (`i`) however you like within each iteration, .

Comment: This did it! Converting it to a string as you commented and making it a list fixed the problem. Thank you so much!!!